# using MailMessage to send email and encode subject for French text

Tags: c#, mailmessage

I am trying to send an email with the following subject in French using C# `MailMessage`.

"Rendez-vous pour l'étude" should show like "Rendez-vous pour l'étude" but it is not converting it correctly. But if I send the same text in email body and use `IsEmailBody = True` then it is correctly showing on the email body but not the subject. I tried encoding subject (`SubjectEncoding`) to UTF8, 16, 7, 32, ANSI, ASCII, Default and it is not working.

Comment: Some code would be nice.

Comment: What do you mean by IsEmailBody=true? Code would really be nice.

Comment: subject: Rendez-vous pour l'&eacute;tude

Comment: using (var message = new MailMessage(fromSource, recipients))
            {
                                
                message.Body = messageText;
                message.Subject = subject;
                message.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;// GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
                message.IsBodyHtml = true;

                

                // Send 
                client.Send(message);
            }

Comment: sorry it is IsBodyHtml = true